# Are Azure Function Bindings Executed in Order?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In a given Azure Function, I can have 1 or more output bindings. For example, I might have a blob storage output (writing a file blob to storage) and a queue output (pushing a message into a queue).

For example, if I have this very simple Azure function (written in Node.js)...

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('START: Multi-output function.');

    context.bindings.outputBlob = "blob-contents";
    context.bindings.outputQueueItem = "{'message': 'hello!'}";

    context.done();
};
```

... with the output bindings set up in `function.json` as follows...

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "outcontainer/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "name": "outputQueueItem",
      "queueName": "outqueue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

... when do the two output bindings actually fire, and in which order?

For the **when** part of the question:

1. Do they fire at the point where the function sets the output binding? (e.g. the line of code that sets `context.bindings.outputBlob`)
2. Do they fire at/after `context.done()`?

For the **order** part of the question:

3. Do they fire in the order they're seen in the code?
4. Do they fire in the order they're seen in `function.json` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output bindings fire after the function execution is completed - after `context.done()`.

The order that you set them in the code has no influence on binding executions.

If you can, treat the actual execution order as the implementation detail and do not rely on it. Having said that, if I'm not mistaken, the actual order will be:

- Execute all non-queue bindings in order of `function.json`
- Then, execute all queue bindings in order of `function.json`

UPDATE: based on [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/921) and [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1025) I conclude that order is not guaranteed at the moment.

Comment: Chris from the Azure Functions team here. Mikhail is correct; we have no promises in the ordering of output bindings.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. Is this likely to remain the state of things? I have a function with two outputs - a queue, and a blob - I want to know that the blob has been successfully written before the queue message has been written...is this possible?

Comment: (my experiments https://github.com/martinpeck/azure-function-with-multiple-output-bindings suggest this is not possible)